# Connect to PostgreSQL using R (in windows)

Tags: r, postgresql

I have this R code and i want to connect to a postgres db using the conf file:

```
con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), groups='epl')
```

The postgresql.conf file contains:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Add settings for extensions here
[epl]
host='localhost'
port = 5432
dbname='rlearning'
user='user'
password='pass'
```

When I run the R code, i get this error:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  unused argument(s) (groups = "epl")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If everything else fails, you can try reading the documentation and following the examples. For `help(dbConnect)`, you find

```
# create an PostgreSQL instance and create one connection.
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

# open the connection using user, passsword, etc., as
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "postgres")
```

and this is where you add additional user, password, host, arguments.

It will also show you *that there is no argument `groups`* explaining the error you get.

Comment: it's unclear to me how this conf file works; i was just trying out an example in a book, but this part is a bit blurry

Comment: Well `psql` may read it, but I do not think we ever added that to the package.